# Remove specific rows from a structure

Tags: matlab, matrix, structure, rows

I have a 1x1 structure (EEG) with 42 fields. One of these fields is called *event* and is a 1x180 structure, with 13 different fields, some of which are strings and some numeric values.

The 4th field of EEG.event is *type* and it contains strings (i.e. 'preo', 'pred', 'to', 'td', 'po', 'pd').

I would like to keep only those rows of the structure that contain 'preo' in the column EEG.event.type.

My ultimate aim is to create a matrix with all the columns from the structure EEG.event and only the rows with 'preo' in EEG.event.type, plus other columns from other variables.

So far I tried:

```
S = struct2table(EEG.event);
```

and it correctly returns a 180x13 table.
However I was not able to select only the rows with 'preo' in *type*. I tried:

```
A= S(S.type=='preo', :);
```

and it gives me an error:

```
 Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

I also tried:

```
array(strcmp(S(:, 4), 'preo'), :) = [];
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Deletion requires an existing variable.
```

Then I thought that maybe I should have converted the table into matrix, to directly delete rows from the matrix. I tried:

```
B = cell2mat(S);
```

but it returns this error:

```
Error using cell2mat (line 42)
You cannot subscript a table using only one subscript. Table subscripting requires both row and variable subscripts.
```

Any suggestion or tip is welcome, because I don't know how to continue.

Example list that I have (only 18 rows here):

```
13  1   201011  'preo'  2502    201 1   1   'y' 'h' 13  13.9230000000000    13
14  1   201011  'pred'  2684    201 1   1   'y' 'h' 14  14.1049999960000    14
15  1   201012  'to'    2707    201 1   2   'y' 'h' 15  14.1280000000000    15
16  1   201012  'td'    2993    201 1   2   'y' 'h' 16  14.4140000000000    16
17  1   201013  'po'    3019    201 1   3   'y' 'h' 17  14.4400000000000    17
18  1   201013  'pd'    3383    201 1   3   'y' 'h' 18  14.8040000000000    18
55  2   61011   'preo'  8213    61  1   1   'y' 'h' 55  53.9000000000000    55
56  2   61011   'pred'  8522    61  1   1   'y' 'h' 56  54.2089999850000    56
57  2   61012   'to'    8547    61  1   2   'y' 'h' 57  54.2340000000000    57
58  2   61012   'td'    8834    61  1   2   'y' 'h' 58  54.5210000000000    58
59  2   61013   'po'    8858    61  1   3   'y' 'h' 59  54.5450000000000    59
60  2   61013   'pd'    9091    61  1   3   'y' 'h' 60  54.7780000000000    60
85  3   124011  'preo'  13924   124 1   1   'y' 'h' 85  82.4550000000000    85
86  3   124011  'pred'  14159   124 1   1   'y' 'h' 86  82.6899999990000    86
87  3   124012  'to'    14181   124 1   2   'y' 'h' 87  82.7120000000000    87
88  3   124012  'td'    14448   124 1   2   'y' 'h' 88  82.9790000000000    88
89  3   124013  'po'    14470   124 1   3   'y' 'h' 89  83.0010000000000    89
90  3   124013  'pd'    14713   124 1   3   'y' 'h' 90  83.2440000000000    90
```

Example list that I would like to have (from the 18 rows above):

```
13  1   201011  'preo'  2502    201 1   1   'y' 'h' 13  13.9230000000000    13
55  2   61011   'preo'  8213    61  1   1   'y' 'h' 55  53.9000000000000    55
85  3   124011  'preo'  13924   124 1   1   'y' 'h' 85  82.4550000000000    85
```

Comment: dunno which list are you applying this filter, could you provide a concrete example.

Comment: @Agawa001 I just added a list of what I have, and what I would like to obtain.

Comment: Did you read the MATLAB docs titled [_Create Table from Subset of Larger Table_](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html#bt1552e-1)? It would be helpful if you could save your `table` to a `.mat` file, upload it somewhere, and post a link to it here... Otherwise I don't see how we can reproduce your problem..

Comment: @Dev-iL me too, i dont believe i can handle EEG structures maybe something in my matlab is missing

Comment: @dede if you want the result without gettin thru EEG.event.type, i can help with that

Comment: @Agawa001, yes, if you could give me any hint, I would really appreciate.

Comment: @dede i dunno i cant replicate your steps i dont have toolbox, but try `strncmp(A.textdata(:, 4), '''preo',5)` or `strncmp(S(:, 4), 'preo',4)` instead of `strcmp(S(:, 4), 'preo')`

Comment: @Agawa001. Thanks for the answer! If I try `strcmp(S(:, 4), 'preo')` it returns `ans = 0`, while I'm not sure what you meant with `A.textdata`. Also, I'm using Matlab_R2015b, but I'm not using any toolbox when I run this script - or at least I'm not aware of calling any toolbox o.O

Comment: try `strncmp(S(:, 4), 'preo',4)` does it come to light ?

Comment: `A.textdata` is resulted from `A = importdata('whatever.csv')`

Comment: @Agawa001, my bad! I didn't report in my previous comment that I tried already `strncmp(S(:, 4), 'preo',4)` and it returns `ans=0`, because only inserting `strcmp(S(:, 4), 'preo')` gives `Error using strncmp Not enough input arguments.`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I post it here for others with my same issue.

I first create a cell array, and then I delete rows from the cell array. At the moment is the best I can think of.

```
myCell= struct2cell(EEG.event);
%it results in a 3d cell array, with the fields as first dimension (42) x a singleton dimension as second dimension x the number of the rows as third dimension (180)
new_Cell = permute(myCell,[3,1,2]);
%it deletes the singleton dimension and swap the other 2 dimensions, obtaining 180x42.
[r,c] = find(strcmp(new_Cell,'preo'));
%indices as rows (r) and columns (c) of cells with the string 'preo'
y = new_Cell([r],:);
%It keeps only the rows that you want from the original cell array 'myCell'.
```